# Page refresh goes back to home page when using History.js in ie9 and below

Tags: javascript, history.js

I've built a site that uses the History.js plugin to navigate from page to page with AJAX and update the URL accordingly. All works well except in IE; when you refresh the page it essentially loads the content from the first page you came to, not the current pages content. In "decent" browsers it doesn't load the content from any page, it just loads the entire page for that URL, which is what I IE should do.

I'm thinking it doesn't understand what to do with the hash. If you visit http://www.crownacre.voyced.com/contact-us/ it works fine, but when you visit http://www.crownacre.voyced.com/#contact-us/ (with the hash) it doesn't.

I've attempted to redirect the page if it detects a # in the pathname, but there is no way of detecting this as window.location.pathname and History.getHash() returns the path without any hash.

Any suggestions? I've seen a few websites using this plugin that have the same problem, and similar issues on here, but no solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi, I have the same issue with history.js in IE8/9, when I refresh, IE loads the first page and not the current page like other html5 browsers do. Could you please help how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<script>
    var url = new String(document.location);
    if (url.indexOf("#") > -1) {
        alert("There is a Hash in the path");
    }
</script>
```

**Edit:**

```
function LocationTest()
{
    var loc = window.location;
    alert(loc.href);
    alert(loc.protocol + "//" + loc.host + loc.pathname + loc.search + loc.hash);
    alert(loc.href == loc.protocol + "//" + loc.host + loc.pathname + loc.search + loc.hash);
}
```

Sample Source: [window.location explained](http://tundrablue.com/development/JavaScript/WindowLocation.html?SearchParameter=true#HashID)

Comment: Yep, this does the job. Although not the perfect solution, as it displays the preceding page for a split second. Once you continue navigating the URL gets a bit screwed up: 'clients/#/services/?&suid...' which is a bit messy, but hey, its mostly ie users who   have no idea what's going on anyway.  Can you explain to me why window.location.pathname and  History.getHash() wouldn't return a 'hash'?

Comment: `location.href` should have given you the same result. `document.location` is a strongly typed object which has a lot of properties, among them the `hash` property which would have also given you the hash (only the hash) of your url. Casting the object to a string should give you the same as `location.href`. I am not very familiar with `History.js`, so I could not tell you for sure why it did not work for you. I have updated the code to display a couple of examples using document.location.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem in my rewrite of tarheelreader.org. I'm using History.js and it is working fine except for the refresh issue in IE8. This hack is working for me.

In my startup code that only runs on initial page load I do:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf('#') > -1) {
    // ie refresh hack
    controller.stateChange();
}
```

where `controller.stateChange()` is the state change handler I use for all History changes.

```
function stateChange() {
    // handle changes in the URL
    var hist = History.getState(),
        url = hist.url,
        context = hist.data;
    renderUrl(url, context).then(function(title) {
        document.title = title;
    });
}
```

You can see all the code in main.js and controller.js at https://github.com/gbishop/TarHeelReaderTheme

**Edit**
Further exploration has lead to a case where History.js uses the initial URL instead of the root. This hack seems to handle that case.

```
function stateChange() {
    // handle changes in the URL
    var hist = History.getState(),
        url = hist.url,
        bar = window.location.href,
        context = hist.data;
    //console.log("State changed...", url, context);
    if (url != bar && bar.indexOf('#') > -1) {
        //console.log('bar = ', bar);
        // I think we only get here in IE8
        // hack for hash mode urls
        var root = History.getRootUrl(),
            hashIndex = bar.indexOf('#');
        if (root != bar.slice(0, hashIndex)) {
            // try to fix the url
            url = root + bar.slice(hashIndex);
            //console.log('new url =', url);
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
    renderUrl(url, context).then(function(title) {
        document.title = title;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks good to me, but it also look a bit complicated, which is why I went with @Hanlet Escaño answer. Cheers!

Comment: The complication is in taking care of the various issues such as the URL getting screwed up as you described in your comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a solution:
Can you please try the History.js unofficial version 1.8a2 of my fork from:
https://github.com/andreasbernhard/history.js

...and give feedback? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but no luck i'm afraid. I get the following error in ie7: 'location.href' is null or not an object. No error in ie8, but still no luck. Not tested in ie9 yet...

Comment: Hanlets answer will do the job for now, but i'll add this issue to your git hub page in a bit more detail so you can hopefully fix it. Thanks and keep up the awesome work!